# How to enter all the elements of a list in a single line without going on to new line in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to enter all the elements of a python list in one single line without pressing Enter.

For Example:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l = [raw_input() for i in xrange(5)]
1
2
3
4
5
```

Instead of this I want to enter like

```
>>> ...
1 2 3 4 5
```

Any help or pointers will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit less verbose:

```
numbers = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you could just split the result of raw_input(), like this?

```
>>> raw_input().split()
1 2 3 4 5
-> ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Alternatively do something with the input elements:

```
[ int(x) for x in raw_input().split()  ]
1 2 3 4 5
-> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = raw_input()
1 2 3 4 5
>>> numbers = [int(num) for num in text.split()]
>>> numbers
0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in a Python script, but not in an interactive interpreter:

```
l = []
while len(l) < 5:
  l.extend(raw_input().split())
print l
```

Using this solution, it doesn't matter if you press *Enter* or not, you can also write a combination of spaces and *Enter*s, but you have to finish with an *Enter*.